# How to submit active tab's form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My question: How do I auto-submit my ACTIVE tab's form using jquery/javascript?

I'm using bootstrap.

Tabs example :

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills-homepage" id="tabsMenuID">
   <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#firstTab" data-toggle="tab">content1</a></li>
   <li role="presentation"><a href="#secondTab" data-toggle="tab">content2</a></li>
</ul>
```

In every tab I have a form to submit.

JS file :

```
function autoSubmit(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('getActivetabHere').(GETactiveTab'sSubmitButton).trigger('click');
    },597000);
}
```

If there's an easier way to submit, I wouldn't like to trigger form's submit button.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you need to look up the tab, the form should be visible (unless for some reason you hide it on the active tab)

```
$('form:visible').submit();
```

Comment: Simple as that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can  get the id of active tab, then using that find out the form and trigger the submit event

```
var tab=$('#tabsMenuID li.active a').attr('href');
$(tab).find('form').submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery to find the tab that is active and submit the containing form

```
$('a[data-toggle=tab]').each(function(){
   if(($this).parent().hasClass('active')){
      ($this).find('form').submit();
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but active tabs are visible.

Comment: Can you not combine the selectors into something like `a[data-toggle=tab]:visible`?

Comment: yep you could combine them.

Comment: I've updated my answer to look at the class of the parent list item.  I have left the selectors seperate, you could do it either way